# What are quotes in Neviim that mention justice?

Tags: navi-prophets, beit-din-court, quotations

I'm looking for some quotations in Neviim that discuss the idea of justice.

**Are there any verses in Neviim that discuss justice?**

Comment: Might as well just copy-paste Neviim Achronim into an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, certainly there are many. But can you (or anyone else) name some good, contextually independent, (possibly famous) quotes that can be highlighted?

Comment: Not constructive? Seems like a polling q.

Comment: @HodofHod, I'm not asking for everyone's favorite. I'm looking for a few that might shed light on what the Neviim thought justice was ([_not_ the 'Amos quote](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25614/5)), or the importance of it (like when HaShem is pleased with Shlomo for his request to be endowed with wisdom to be a good judge instead of wealth, and rewards him with both).

Comment: So the Amos one is not what you're looking for? Sorry! I must have misunderstood the question. Is the Isaiah one closer to what you're looking for? There are a few other similar places in Nevi'im: the tropes of helping the widow and orphan and of abandoning evil deeds are pretty common. One of the main themes of classical prophecy, according to biblical scholars, is that G!d's covenant contains both ritual and ethical obligations ("ritual is meaningless without social justice"), and that gets expressed pretty clearly throughout. I can write another answer about that if you'd prefer.

Comment: As an aside, יִרְמְיָהוּ and שׁוֹפְטִים have very different views on what justice is.  Neviim rishonim and acharonim are very different here.

Comment: Just approved an anonymous edit to this question. ....why not just search "משפט" (or, probably the better option, "שפט") in your favorite Tanach search engine? ....Torat Emet gives me 83 hits for "שפט" in less than two seconds.

Comment: ^^^ correction on above comment: I accidently searched only Chumash instead of Navi. Searching Navi yielded 214 hits, although skimming the results showed that "יהושפט" was included ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I second DoubleAA's comment - I'm hard pressed to think of a *navi* who doesn't talk about justice.

The most immediate quote for me is Amos 5:24:

*Let justice roll down like waters, righteousness like a mighty stream.*

Other candidates include:

Micah 6:8: *It has been told to you, O mortal, what is good and what the L!RD seeks from you: only to do justice, to love kindness, and to walk humbly with your G!d.*

Isaiah 1:16-17: *Wash yourselves, cleanse yourselves, take your evil deeds away, out of My sight; stop doing evil. Learn to do good, seek justice, gladden the oppressed, defend the orphan, fight for the widow.*

There are many many more, but those are the ones that spring to mind. And they are certainly famous, or at least well known. The Amos one in particular - it is quoted in MLK's "I Have A Dream" speech, and it is engraved on the wall of the Civil Rights Memorial in Montgomery, and the MLK National Memorial in Washington, DC.